# Replace output from variable PHP

Tags: php

I wrote this rule to check if a user is in a specific group. But when executing, `$result` shows a "1" as output to show it's true that the user is member of that group.

```
$result = $adldap->user()->inGroup('john.doe', 'Testgroup', $recursive=NULL);
print_r($result);
```

How can I replace this output to a custom `echo` message for example?

I'm using this PHP class for my project: http://adldap.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if($result == 1) {
  echo "Whatever you want";
} else {
  echo "User is not in group";
}
```

Comment: I tested it and now i'm still getting the "1" and right after that the first echo? Like this: "1Whatever you want". It's not replacing.

Comment: did you remove the `print_r($result);`?

Comment: Ah, that was the problem, thanks. It works perfect now.